# I can't activate my virtual environment in PowerShell

Tags: python, django, powershell

When i try activate my virtual environment in CMD, doesn't exit any problem but in PowerShell i'm having that error:

```
PS C:\Users\Burak\desktop\my-site\myenv\Scripts> activate.bat
activate.bat : The term 'activate.bat' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check t
he spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ activate.bat
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (activate.bat:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundExceptionenter code here
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

try activate or ./activate instead activate.bat
if it don't help then try this:

> You need to set windows execution policies. According to official
> documentation of virtualenv.
>
> Run in powershell
>
> ```
> Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
> > -Scope CurrentUse
> ```
>
> Now you can activate virtual env. using \Scripts\Activate.ps1
>
> Hope it solves it!